# Issues with creating label for our M1 erp software

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert an SQL that was written for a previous version of our software. It is grabbing information from an input form, placing them in a temporary table and calculating number of labels and printing a crystal report label accordingly

I have tried changing syntax and removing a where clause ( it is commented out in my code below) that i was unable to link to anything in our new version.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @nloop int, @nLabels int
DECLARE @rmlReceiptID varchar(10), @rmlReceiptLineID int, @urmlNOofLabels int
DECLARE LabelsCursor CURSOR READ_ONLY FOR SELECT @rmlReceiptID, @rmlReceiptLineID, @urmlNOofLabels FROM ReceiptLines /* WHERE {?WHERECLAUSE}*/ ORDER BY rmlReceiptID, rmlReceiptLineID

CREATE TABLE #UReceiptLabel (rmlReceiptID varchar(10), rmlReceiptLineID int, CurrentLabel int, TotalLabels int) 
SELECT @rmlReceiptID,@rmlReceiptLineID,CONVERT(int,0) As CurrentLabel,CONVERT(int,0) As TotalLabels insert into #UReceiptLabel from ReceiptLines WHERE 0=1

OPEN LabelsCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM LabelsCursor INTO @rmlReceiptID, @rmlReceiptLineID, @urmlNOofLabels

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @nloop = 0
    SET @nLabels = @urmlNOofLabels
    IF @nLabels < 1
        SET @nLabels = 1

    WHILE (@nloop < @nLabels)
    BEGIN
        SET @nloop = @nloop + 1
        INSERT INTO #UReceiptLabel (rmlReceiptID, rmlReceiptLineID, CurrentLabel, TotalLabels) VALUES (@rmlReceiptID, @rmlReceiptLineID, @nloop, @nLabels)
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM LabelsCursor INTO @rmlReceiptID, @rmlReceiptLineID, @urmlNOofLabels
END

CLOSE LabelsCursor
DEALLOCATE LabelsCursor
SET NOCOUNT OFF
SELECT CurrentLabel, TotalLabels, ReceiptLines.rmlReceiptID, ReceiptLines.rmlReceiptLineID, rmlJobID, rmlPartID, rmlJobQuantityReceived, urmlNoOfLabels, urmlQtyInABox, urmlLocation,rmpSupplierOrganizationID, cmoName, rmlDescription, rmlJobAssemblyID
FROM #UReceiptLabel 
INNER JOIN ReceiptLines ON ReceiptLines.rmlReceiptID = #UReceiptLabel.rmlReceiptID and ReceiptLines.rmlReceiptLineID = #UReceiptLabel.rmlReceiptLineID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Receipts ON rmpReceiptID = #UReceiptLabel.rmlReceiptID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Organizations On rmpSupplierOrganizationID=cmoOrganizationID ORDER BY #UReceiptLabel.rmlReceiptID,#UReceiptLabel.rmlReceiptLineID,CurrentLabel
DROP TABLE #UReceiptLabel
```

when i attempt to run the crystal report i get An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. 
I would expect the crystal report to parse the input data and fill the label with appropriate information and print the correct number of labels.

Comment: You should research tally tables. You don't need or want to use a loop here.

Comment: The error is because you are inserting your variables into a temp table but you don't provide an alias for those variables so it doesn't know what name you want for the temp table. There are numerous syntactical and logical errors all over this code.